# Excel formula - probably an easy one for most of you

Tags: worksheet-function

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhDd9.jpg)Can anyone help with an excel formula - I need to keep a running over/short total for several people who owe 15/week for 30 weeks.  If they pay 15 for the week, the running total should be at 0, if they pay 20 for the next week, they would have a $5 over total, if the next week they don't pay, they would have a $10 short total.  I'm not sure why I'm having such a hard time with this formula.
John Smith:  Week 1 pays $15, wk2 pays $15, wk3 pays $20, wk4 pays $0, wk5 pays $0
his running over short total should equal -$5
His overal shorts for 30 weeks would still be -400, that is an easy enough formula, but I want the formula to show the over/shorts to date which would be the -5

Comment: The formula you use would depend on your setup, but SUMIF() with a relative range is what you want.  Hard to get more detailed than that without test data formatted like your sheet.

Comment: please create a table with the information as you have it, does each person have their own table are the intermixed.  T

Comment: Over/short to date wk1 wk2 wk3 wk4 wk5 wk6 wk7
 Jane Smith 0                       15 15 0 0 40 20 0
me            -30                    0 15 15 0   
John Smith 25                         20 20 20 20 20  
him                  -15                    15 15 0 30 15 0

Comment: sorry, I tried to enter it as a table so you could see it better, but it didn't work

Comment: put it in the original post not in the comments.  then highlight the text and hit Ctrl-k.

Comment: got the table in there - I need the formula to be current for each based on them owing 15/week

Comment: There are no negative or values, so I don't see how one can figure debt or credit based on the values displayed.

Comment: I think I got it to work - the formula would be  ...for anyone else who might need it is:   =SUM(E375:AG377)-COUNTA(E375:AG377)

Answer (score 1):

use this formula:

```
=COUNT(C2:R2)*(AVERAGE(C2:R2)-15)
```

[image]

Comment: that formula works great also - thanks so very much for your help and time.